# Mongodb pull from array attached to simple schema

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following collection attached to aldeed:simple schema

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

Posts.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    samplePost:{
        type:String,
        max:500
    },
    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        autoValue: function(){
            return new Date()
        }
    },
    "comments.$.reply":{
        type:String
    },
    "comments.$.commentId":{
        type: String,
        autoValue: function(){
            var tempCommentId = new Meteor.Colletion.ObjectID();
            return tempCommentId.str;
        }
    },
    "comments.$.commentCreatedAt": {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        autoValue: function(){
            return new Date()
        }
    },
});
```

The actual document looks like the following:

```
{
    "_id": "aaa",
    "samplePost": "Hello world!",
    "comments": [
        {
            "reply": "Goodbye",
            "commentId": "bbb", 
            "createdAt": "2016-06-19T19:06:17.931Z"
        },
        {
            "reply": "Good morning",
            "commentId": "ccc"
            "createdAt": "2016-06-19T19:05:17.931Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

Now im trying to remove only the 2nd comment with commentId:"ccc" from the document with $pull

```
"click #delete-comment": function(event, template){
    var tempCommentId = $(event.target).parent().find('#commentIdPass').text();     //commentId is collected from HTML view
    Posts.update(
        {_id: template.data._id},   //_id is collected from the url param
        {$pull:{
            comments: {
                commentId: tempCommentId
            }}
        });
},
```

and this is not working. I have narrowed down the problem to

```
"comments.$.commentCreatedAt": {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function(){
        return new Date()
    }
},
```

schema.  If i remove this schema, i can delete the comment.
So, why is this causing a problem of pulling the whole comment item from the array.  Any ideas? Any workarounds?

Comment: Do you want to remove that particular element of an array or u want to update it!!!

Comment: I am trying to remove it by using the $pull command

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query:

db.getCollection('Mytest').update({"_id":"aaa"},{"$pull":{"comments":{"commentId":"ccc"}}});

Comment: thanks for looking into the problem.  i have solved it by adding conditional to the schema's autovalue function.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  As I have suspected attached schema was the culprit.  I needed to set a conditional for inserting and updating a schema with autovalue method.  The schema should look as following:

```
"comments.$.commentCreatedAt": {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function () {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return new Date;
        }
    }
},
```